# PHP Mail Function with Multiple Table Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a script that allows visitors to enter their email address to receive a notification upon a photo upload by other users.  For testing purposes, I used this code to query just my "email" table, and it works perfectly when a new photo is uploaded:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT email
    FROM email");


if(! $data )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
if($info = mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC))
$email=$info['email'];
{

mail($email, 'Test Email', $message);
```

However, the necessary query will involve 2 tables (to compare info that was tagged during photo upload to info that was provided by the user wishing to receive the email). However, when I use the following query, no email is sent.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT person.event, person.name, email.event, email.name, email.email
    FROM person, email
    WHERE '$event' = email.event and '$name' = email.name");


if(! $data )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
if($info = mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC))
$email=$info['email.email'];
{

mail($email, 'Test Message', $message);
```

I'm pretty new to php, so I suspect that I'm missing something obvious.  I'd appreciate any corrections. Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not joining the tables in any way. can you show the table structure, what columns relate person to email?

Comment: Do the columns `person.event` and `email.event` relate the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your query is correct, and fetchs the data you need, a problem I found is that you're getting an email.email member from the mysql result array, and you should only get

> $email=$info['email'];

there is no table namespace into the mysql results... so if you have to ask for two fields with the same name you have to use an AS clause, and rename one of them.

In addition, you could use the "print_r" php function to output the array fetched and debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are doing a cross join on two tables.

```
SELECT person.event, person.name, email.event, email.name, email.email
FROM person, email  //Implicit join syntax is evil.
WHERE '$event' = email.event and '$name' = email.name
```

Never use implicit SQL '89 join syntax, It's an anti-pattern.
Use explicit join syntax instead.
Change the query to:

```
$event = mysql_real_escape_string($event);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

$sql = "SELECT p.event, p.name, e.event, e.name, e.email
FROM person p
INNER JOIN email e ON (e.person_id = p.id)
WHERE e.event = '$event' AND e.name = '$name' ";
```

You might need to tweak the join criterion to match on the relevant fields.
e.g. if you have emailaddress as the PK for person, you'd need:

```
INNER JOIN email e ON (e.emailaddress = p.emailaddress)
```